# Access to a ES6 / ES7 static class variable within class and constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, static, ecmascript-2016

I'm having a pretty strange problem:

```
class AddOrSelectAddress {
    static allCountries = {
        AD: "Andorra",
        AE: "Vereinigte Arabische Emirate",
        AF: "Afghanistan",
        // ...
    };

    constructor() {
        console.log('new');
        console.log(this.allCountries); // prints "undefined"
    }
}

const myInstance = new AddOrSelectAddress();
```

Why does that happen? I would expect, that the `this.allCountries` would contain the object there.

Comment: _"Static methods are not directly accessible using the `this` keyword from non-static methods. You need to call them using the class name: `CLASSNAME.STATIC_METHOD_NAME()` or by calling the method as a property of the constructor: `this.constructor.STATIC_METHOD_NAME()`."_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)) - It's for methods but I would guess that this will also count for properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods and properties are accessible through classes, not through *this* keyword:

```js
class AddOrSelectAddress {
    static allCountries = {
        AD: "Andorra",
        AE: "Vereinigte Arabische Emirate",
        AF: "Afghanistan",
        // ...
    };

    constructor() {
        console.log('new');
        console.log(AddOrSelectAddress.allCountries);
    }
}

const myInstance = new AddOrSelectAddress();
```

Comment: Minor nit: it's a property, not a method (methods are properties that are functions).

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the solution. Can I somehow make that static property private?

Comment: @AndréReichelt   `static #allCountries = {...};` will be both static and private

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Thank you very much! pretty "special" syntax, though. Looks like JS wants to be extra fancy.